# How to know Overlay Icon status?

Tags: c#, shell, icons

In applications such as Dropbox , TortoiseSvn there are small icon's attached to the bottom of the file icon.

How can i get the overlay icon of these files . that means i want to know which files use icon A, and which files use icon B in order to know file sync status.

Is there any way in c# to do this?

Comment: If you are after file sync status, you may be able to obtain that from the SVN APIs rather than reverse engineer it from the appearance of icons.  If you go the icon route, be aware that it is subject to delays; caching and being disabled by users.

Comment: @MickyD , i considered that way , but i have special requirement , i have to get the Overlay Icon . so any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

This code will allow you to extract the associated icon from a file in windows.

```
var sysicon = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(ExePath);
var bmpSrc = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(
                                    sysicon.Handle,
                                    System.Windows.Int32Rect.Empty,
                                    System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
                        sysicon.Dispose();
                        bmpSrc.Freeze();
                        fileIcon = bmpSrc;
```

Comment: File icons are not the same thing as _overlay icons_.  One is embedded in the file or provided by an application.   Overlay icons are superimposed over the former.

Comment: yes , @Thimmoth , i need Overlay Icons NOT file icon , can you help me ?